# Alternative to testrail, with support for sso (saml, oauth)

Tags: testrail

We have been using cloud-based testrail for a few years. We are mostly happy, but the lack of a single sign-on solution is hampering adoption (see [1] and [2]).

My question is this: Are there any other online test management services that have the feature level of testrail, but that also includes SSO-support?

Eirik

1. https://discuss.gurock.com/t/sso-integration-using-saml-adfs/3721
2. https://discuss.gurock.com/t/feature-request-saml-sso-via-okta/1939

Comment: Have you run across [this potential solution](https://github.com/gurock/testrail-auth) for testrail?

Comment: The solution by @AlexHall is for the self-hosted version of testrail. I have edited the question to clarify that I am asking about a hosted (cloud) solution.

Answer (score 0):

TestRail now supports SSO using OAUTH, OpenID or SAML. You can refer to the TestRail SSO configuration documentation at,

https://www.gurock.com/testrail/docs/admin/enterprise/configure-sso/

You will need to upgrade your TestRail license to Enterprise level license and then follow the configuration process mentioned above.